# Making blueimp jquery file upload work with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I've read some other questions here on SO regarding this issue but I can't seem to find a COMPLETE answer on how to make it works.

So, I already have a controller called project and I'd like to add multiple file upload to it, what do I need to do ?

I've copied the source code from their demo page ([Demo Page](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html)) and added the 'blueimp.fileupload' module to my controller. That's all I've done so far.

Thank you very much.

Edit:

My .html code:

```
<div ng-include="'partials/navbar.html'"></div>

<script language="javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('#urgenteDiv').tooltip()

        $.validate({
            modules: 'date,security'
        });

    })

    function barra(objeto) {

        if (objeto.value.length == 2 || objeto.value.length == 5) {
            objeto.value = objeto.value + "/";
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md -4 col-md-offset-2 ">
        <form role="form" class="form form-horizontal" name="form" ng-submit="register(form)" novalidate>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Novo Projeto</legend>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"
                               data-validation="required" ng-model="prpject.name" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Linguagem de Programação" class="form-control" name="language"
                               id="language" data-validation="required"
                               ng-model="project.language" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Data de entrega" onKeyUp="barra(this)"
                               id="birthday" name="deliver_date" maxlength="10" data-validation="date"
                               data-validation-format="dd/mm/yyyy" ng-model="project.deliver_date" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nº de participantes" id="numParticipants"
                               name="numParticipants" data-validation="number"
                               ng-model="project.numParticipants" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label name="urgenteDiv" id="urgenteDiv" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                   data-placement="right"
                                   title="Marque esta opção se este projeto necessita ser feito num prazo muito curto.">
                                <input type="checkbox"> É urgente
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Email de participantes</strong></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-file-upload="options" data-ng-class="{'fileupload-processing': processing() || loadingFiles}">
        <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
        <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" ng-class="{disabled: disabled}">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple ng-disabled="disabled">
                </span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start" data-ng-click="submit()">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <!-- The global file processing state -->
                <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress state -->
            <div class="col-lg-5 fade" data-ng-class="{in: active()}">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" data-file-upload-progress="progress()"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" data-ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div></div>
                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table class="table table-striped files ng-cloak">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="file in queue" data-ng-class="{'processing': file.$processing()}">
                <td data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.thumbnailUrl">
                    <div class="preview" data-ng-switch-when="true">
                        <a data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}" data-gallery><img data-ng-src="{{file.thumbnailUrl}}" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="preview" data-ng-switch-default data-file-upload-preview="file"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="name" data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.url">
                        <span data-ng-switch-when="true" data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.thumbnailUrl">
                            <a data-ng-switch-when="true" data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}" data-gallery>{{file.name}}</a>
                            <a data-ng-switch-default data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}">{{file.name}}</a>
                        </span>
                        <span data-ng-switch-default>{{file.name}}</span>
                    </p>
                    <strong data-ng-show="file.error" class="error text-danger">{{file.error}}</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="size">{{file.size | formatFileSize}}</p>
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active fade" data-ng-class="{pending: 'in'}[file.$state()]" data-file-upload-progress="file.$progress()"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" data-ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start" data-ng-click="file.$submit()" data-ng-hide="!file.$submit || options.autoUpload" data-ng-disabled="file.$state() == 'pending' || file.$state() == 'rejected'">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                        <span>Start</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel" data-ng-click="file.$cancel()" data-ng-hide="!file.$cancel">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                        <span>Cancel</span>
                    </button>
                    <button data-ng-controller="FileDestroyController" type="button" class="btn btn-danger destroy" data-ng-click="file.$destroy()" data-ng-hide="!file.$destroy">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

                <button ng-disabled="form.$invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Cadastrar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I described what I've tried. It is not showing the files when I select them on the table with the multiple files. Thanks

Comment: Provide us the code to help better understand what is issue or any errors.

Comment: There you go ! Thanks

Comment: I think I got it how the .html should be, I just need to understand now how the upload controller should be to work just like in the example. Thanks again !